# Exposed Filter Input Token

Tags: views, tokens

Quick question, is there a token that can be used within the drupal ui to grab what has been typed into a exposed filter text box.

I am asking because, for example, when a user applies this filter, if it returns 0 results i want to display the message 'Your search for 'SEARCH_TERM' returned 0 results'.

With SEARCH_TERM being whatever was typed into the input field.

I went into ADMIN->STRUCTURE->VIEWS, chose my views and went to the 'No Results Behaviour' configuration page.

Did the following:
[image]

And i thought this would grab the input in the 'Title' field, but instead it just outputting exactly what is typing into the pictured textbox.

Any help on how i can grab what has been typed in to display in the no results message would be much appreciated.

Thanks